# How would an extradition work when only one of two actions was criminal?

Tags: criminal-law, common-law, civil-legal-system, extradition

Pretend somebody committed two different acts that were considered crimes in their country. This person then fled to another country, where only one of their acts is considered a crime.

In the above example situation, would an extradition be allowed to bring the offender back to their home country? Would there perhaps be some type of agreement between the two countries to only punish the offender for the act which was considered a crime in both jurisdictions, and to drop the other charge?

I ask this question in general, rather than for a specific country overview.  It might be easier to avoid United States law as it tends to get complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Extradition is done for specific charges. A principle found in virtually all extradition treaties called the "rule of specialty" says that the country requesting extradition may not prosecute the defendant for any crimes except the ones for which extradition was granted without the permission of the extraditing country, except for crimes committed after the defendant is extradited. This protection expires once the defendant has been released from jail and had a fair chance to leave the country.

The rule of specialty doesn't necessarily mean the other charge needs to be *dropped*, but the defendant can't be tried for it as long as the rule applies. If they're later in the country for another reason (or don't leave when they have the chance), they can potentially be rearrested for the other crime. But as long as they're only in the country because they were extradited, they can't be tried for any other past crimes without the extraditing country's permission.

Comment: Surely the police would find the criminal's release date, and wait outside of prison to rearrest them?

Comment: @user5623335 You get a reasonable chance to leave. For instance, in the US-Germany extradition treaty, you get 45 days. Under the treaty, the police can't rearrest you the instant you're released.

Comment: Would you happen to know how many days someone would have in the United Kingdom (England and Wales jurisdiction) by any chance?

Comment: @user5623335 The period might vary by treaty. Is there a country you had in mind to be extraditing the person to the UK?

Comment: I forget the UK (England and Wales) is a bit of a mess and that these things are not centralised. I guess Spain and the Republic of Ireland would be two examples that spring to mind.

Comment: @user5623335 Intra-EU extradition/European Arrest Warrant procedure is a bit weird, but the basic timeline is 45 days to leave the country before your protection under the rule of specialty expires.

Comment: I meant, what if a person is extradited from Spain to the UK (England and Wales), how long would they have to escape once released from prison?

Comment: @user5623335 Ah. I think that would also be 45 days, per the UK's Brexit treaty with the EU. That's also the timeline in the 1957 European Convention on Extradition. A more recent ECE update shortened it to 30 days, but I don't think that applies between the UK and Spain or Ireland (since Spain and Ireland didn't sign up to the shorter timeline).